# How can I summarize the result of Lookup values?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've a SSRS Report where one column is a result of Lookup from another dataset.
I need to show the total of this column. 
For each row I'm using the following expression:

```vb
=Lookup(Fields!InstallerID.Value, Fields!InstallerID.Value, 
        Fields!RoutedPoints.Value, "spCapacity_GetRoutedPoint")
```

And for a total row I'm using:

```vb
=Sum(Lookup(Fields!InstallerID.Value, Fields!InstallerID.Value, 
            Fields!RoutedPoints.Value, "spCapacity_GetRoutedPoint"), 
     "spBSA_National_Productivity")
```

But the value is wrong.

How can I get the sum of this column?

Comment: You'll need to tell us what is "wrong" with the calculated value, preferably by creating a small example dataset.